# Compare columns of pandas dataframes and fill missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes as follows.

```
list1 = [{'salt': 0.2, 'fat': 0.8}, {'fat': 1.0, 'protein': 0.9}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(line2)
# Fill missing values with zeros
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)

list2 = [{'salt': 0.1, 'sugar': 0.9}, {'oil': 0.9, 'sugar': 0.8, 'salt': 0.2}, {'protein': 0.9}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(line2)
# Fill missing values with zeros
df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

My two data frames look as follows.

```
df1:
   fat  protein  salt
0  0.8      0.0   0.2
1  1.0      0.9   0.0

df2:
   oil  protein  salt  sugar
0  0.0      0.0   0.1    0.9
1  0.9      0.0   0.2    0.8
2  0.0      0.9   0.0    0.0
```

Now I want to compare df1 and df2 to find missing topics and fill them with zero, so that the final version of the dataframes looks as follows.

```
df1:
   fat  protein  salt  oil  sugar
0  0.8      0.0   0.2   0    0
1  1.0      0.9   0.0   0    0

df2:
   oil  protein  salt  sugar  fat
0  0.0      0.0   0.1    0.9   0
1  0.9      0.0   0.2    0.8   0
2  0.0      0.9   0.0    0.0   0
```

I know to do this within a dataframe using `df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)`. But with two dataframes, how can we do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.align`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) making sure to only align along the column axis.  Use argument `fill_value=0` to fill in missing elements with zero.

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
df1

   fat  oil  protein  salt  sugar
0  0.8    0      0.0   0.2      0
1  1.0    0      0.9   0.0      0
```

---

```
df2

   fat  oil  protein  salt  sugar
0    0  0.0      0.0   0.1    0.9
1    0  0.9      0.0   0.2    0.8
2    0  0.0      0.9   0.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `df.reindex`. Not as elegant, still going to post anyway, since piR hasn't given you [as many options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149202/4909087) this time!

```
c = df1.columns | df2.columns
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=c).fillna(0)
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=c).fillna(0)
```

---

```
df1

   fat  oil  protein  salt  sugar
0  0.8  0.0      0.0   0.2    0.0
1  1.0  0.0      0.9   0.0    0.0


df2

   fat  oil  protein  salt  sugar
0  0.0  0.0      0.0   0.1    0.9
1  0.0  0.9      0.0   0.2    0.8
2  0.0  0.0      0.9   0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Excuse the copying typo.